# Displaying rails custom validation errors next to appropriate field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm embarking on learning about validators in rails and have run into the following issue.

I have a series of form fields on the app that I'm working on.  I've noticed that if I use a validator native to rails such as `validates :pin_number, length: { is: 6 }`, it goes and puts a nice little message next to the form field in question: `<span class="error">is the wrong length (should be 6 characters)</span>`  Awesome!

However, when I created the custom validator below to check the value of :pin_number, my error message, though it appeared at the top, didn't appear next to the field that was in violation.

```
#from my controller hp_id.rb
validates :pin_number, pin: true

#from my custom validator in app/validators/pin_validator.rb
class PinValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each (record, attribute, value)
    if value > 9999
     record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "validator working")
    end
  end
end
```

I looked around online and, while I did find suggestions for editing the input fields to display validation errors, this approach seemed sloppy as certain rails validators already have this functionality without any modification to the view.

**My Question is** how do I take advantage of the existing framework to render a `<span class="error">` message with my own custom validator?

Any insight appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can write all in one line and add your custom message in this way:

```
#Model
validates_numericality_of :pin, :only_integer =>true, 
                          :less_than => 9999, 
                          :message => "Your custom message"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Ultimately my intention is to add a custom message to a custom validator, not to an existing one.  The greater-than less-than test is, itself, just a convenient way of seeing if it's working.